# Components with props as panels for syncfusion dashboard

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, syncfusion

I have an issue with using the Dashboard layout. I want to populate it with react components. The problem I have is that there is no way to do that the normal react way (with props which trigger rerender and such). A panel content can be added as a string or as a HTML element without any dynamic props.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

From the explanation, we weren't clear on your exact requirement for the Dashboard Layout component. Whether you want to add the panel configurations in a fixed way or want to render the Dashboard Layout panel dynamically, please confirm that the component you are using is our Syncfusion Dashboard.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/dashboard-layout/getting-started/

For further validation of this issue, need some additional details. Please share the tried out sample or code snippets.